# How do I tell if a request is for an asset?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I have a middleware component that I use to setup some logging components, but I want to skip some of the setup if the current request is for an asset (anything handled by the asset pipeline). Is there a way I can know in the middleware if the current request is for an asset?

My only thought is I can check the url for '/assets/' but is this the best way?

Comment: In production, you shouldn't even hit your Rails app for assets. They are compiled and put under `/assets/`, your web server (e.g. Nginx) then serves those static files, completely bypassing Rails.

Comment: There is also the [quiet_assets](http://rubygems.org/gems/quiet_assets) gem.

Comment: Yes, this isn't an issue in production. We're concerned about local development (because the extra logic in the middleware is getting executed needlessly on all asset requests and slowing things down.)

Comment: @DMKE I don't believe that gem will prevent middleware from executing for asset requests. However, it looks they're using a similar approach to determining if the request is for an asset... https://github.com/evrone/quiet_assets/blob/master/lib/quiet_assets.rb